# AngularJS+Typescript - Controller inside a directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller, gruntjs, typescript

I am trying to add put my whole class containing the controller inside my directive, put for some obvious reasons scope and syntax is incorrect. 
I am using typescript as language and grunt-ts for the automatic generation and compiling.

```
/// <reference path="../reference.ts" />

directives.directive('myDirective', function ():ng.IDirective {
return {
    restrict: 'EAC',
    template: directiveHTML.html, \\  thanks to grunt-ts this work fine
    controller: MyControllerClass, \\ here I get the error and here I would like to
                                      put my own controller class instead of a function
    link: function (scope, elements, attrs) {
    }
}
```

});

and here the class of my controller

```
module Controllers {
    export class CursorController {
        constructor($scope, socket){
        }
    }
}
```

Where all the controller are then added to the controllers module of angularJS (references are generated automatically by grunt-td).

```
/// <reference path="../reference.ts" />
angular.module('controllers',[]).controller(Controllers);
```

Any clue or suggestion on how to solve this problem would be great.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to do :

```
directives.directive('myDirective', function ():ng.IDirective {
return {
    restrict: 'EAC',
    template: directiveHTML.html, \\  thanks to grunt-ts this work fine
    controller: Controllers.CursorController, \\ Lookup controller by name
    link: function (scope, elements, attrs) {
    }
}
});
```

Comment: I thought I had tried this. It worked like a charm. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest something like this:

```js
export class MyDirective implements ng.IDirective {

    public injection(): Array<any> {
        return [
            () => { return new MyDirective() }
        ]
    }

    public replace: boolean = true;

    public controller = () => {
        console.log('trying');
    }
}
```

And here:

```js
angular.module('myApp', []).directive('myDirective', MyDirective.prototype.injection())
```